does rf remote transmitter power affect solenoid strength
Remote-control nestbox (bird) trap design calls for one 9V battery (pack with switch) boosted to 12V with MT3608 module to power 12V 433Mhz RF remote receiver, which is connected to a ZEY1-0530 solenoid (specs: 12V DC 1A 10mm push pull) that holds the tiny trap door open until remote triggers solenoid plunger to retract releasing door to spring shut.
Solenoid plunger retracts when RF remote transmitter button is pushed, but is too weak to retract when holding the trap door open (sheet metal trap door size/gauge and .4mm torsion spring are to design specs).
The design also called for removing the RF remote transmitter battery and connecting another 9V battery, boosted to 12V with MT3608 module (just like the one connected to the receiver) to the transmitter battery terminals. I didn't do this bc when I tested the transmitter with its own (CR2) battery, it worked to power the receiver, triggering the solenoid to retract.
As mentioned however, once plunger was placed over edge of trap door, the solenoid was too weak to retract the plunger, even though tension from .4mm torsion spring is extremely light.
I know nothing about electronics. I wondered about the transmitter design, but assumed the extra power supply had to do with distance or something. I mean, I didn't think the transmitter's power supply would be related to the amount of power being delivered to the solenoid.
Could it be that the design called for increasing the transmitter's power supply to 12V (the 9V battery boosted to 12V, in place of the CR2 battery) because that somehow increases or helps sustain the amount of current the receiver's power supply is able to deliver to the solenoid?

No. The RF receiver portion of the device will simply supply a logic 1 or 0 to the circuitry controlling the solenoid. Increasing the transmitter power will only increase its range (and is illegal in most jurisdictions).
Your 9V battery could be unsuitable, however. Most 9V batteries are designed for very low current draw over months to years - think remote control or smoke detector - and aren't very good for brief periods of high current like a solenoid. Try a 9V battery designed for high-draw applications.

Thank you. A quick search turned up a "9V lithium high capacity 1300 mAh" battery. Is that the kind of battery you mean?

Probably, but "high capacity" and "high current draw" are not necessarily synonymous.

Thank you. Do you think 8 aa batteries in series would provide enough power for the solenoid? I could fit 8 aa batteries in the nest box if its possible to connect two four packs or four 2 packs to get 8 in series.

You would need 6 AA batteries in series but that would probably work; a 9V battery is just 6 pez-shaped cells stacked together inside the can.

Thank you. I'm so sorry to ask but would I still need the boost module to get 12V from 6aa batteries? I thought it would take 8 to get 12V without the boost module. I swear that's my last question.

Yes, since the voltage of the batteries isn't constant - a 9V battery could be close to 10V out of the box and below 6V when it's "dead" - you need the boost converter to keep the circuit powered at 12V.

Thank you so much.

@vir Actually, not all 9V batteries has the pez cells inside. There are 6LR61s as well - https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-26f06f5558373ce139488a9d8ff1b0fa-lq

Confused. Tried 8AAs in series. Took out boost module since 8AAs have 12V. It worked, but solenoid was still too weak to release door. After several tests, it stopped working at all. Decided to try 6AAs with booster, but forgot to hook booster back up. Solenoid not only worked, it was strong enough to release door. Why would this be if solenoid is 12V (and receiver as well) and 6AAs without booster only have 9V? And why would 8AAs, which have 12V not work?

Additional Q. Took four 2AA packs with switches, connecting black of one pack to red of next. This left red wire on first pack and black wire on last pack free. Tested voltage using these two wires after switching on the first pack only (switches of other three packs off) & tester confirmed 12V. Connected to receiver this way & it worked several times to trigger solenoid, then stopped working. Disconnected same two wires from receiver and tested again, just as before, with only switch of first pack turned on. This time, 0 volts. Turned on all 4 packs, got12V. Why?

Hard to say without knowing the circuit.

One solenoid wire is connected to the negative terminal of the receiver and the other to the NO terminal. Black wire of power supply (here, black wire of fourth 2AA pack) is connected to the Negative terminal and red wire of power supply (here, red wire of first 2AA pack) to the Positive terminal. There is a separate wire that is connected to the Positive and Common terminals of the receiver.

Could I get more current to solenoid if used the two power supply diagram (remote receiver info has single supply diagram and an external supply diagram). Would it make a difference if I used the original 9V with booster, connecting its red to + terminal and its black to - terminal to power the receiver, and then used the 6AAs (with booster? without booster?), connecting the red battery wire to receiver's Common terminal, the black battery wire to one solenoid wire, and connecting the other solenoid wire to the receiver's NO terminal to power the solenoid?

https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/616wCl1xbQL.AC.jpg    the wiring diagram I  used is the first one pictured in this image. Wondering if using the external power supply diagram, which is the second one pictured, would get more current to the solenoid since whatever current the receiver needs to switch on is coming from its own power supply.
